# Mock an object in a method that is not a parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I'm using EasyMock and junit to unit test a project I'm working on, but I'm stumped at this point. An example is below.

```
public ObjectNameHere methodOne(String location) {
    return this.SecondPart.getObjectByLocation(location);
}
```

I want to unit test this by checking that what the method returns is an instanceof ObjectNameHere... but how can I do that without mocking SecondPart (which requires I pass the method a mock object of SecondPart?) ??

Comment: Does `getObjectByLocation` returns some type of interface? Does ObjectNameHere implements this interface? And why would the type matter?

Comment: Ah, my blunder. ObjectNameHere would be an interface.

Comment: How could the method return anything other than `ObjectNameHere` - the compiler statically enforces the type.

Comment: And what is `SecondPart`? Do you follow naming conventions? Is it an inner class with a static method `getObjectByLocation`?

Comment: @mdma - thought about this too - the method could return `null` or any type, which is a direct or multi level subclass of `ObjectNameHere`. Maybe that's his concern.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing the test case for the method **methodOne** or **getObjectByLocation**. Because if it for **methodOne** then you need to mock the **SecondPart** object and expect some return value for the method **getObjectByLocation**. Or if it is for **getObjectByLocation** method then you have to write a test case for the **SecondPart** class.